# DocumentNode.SelectNodes return null (Xpath without tbody)

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I was wondering if you could explain to me what's wrong in my script. My string "driverName"  return always "null". I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack. What i would like to do is to get the all driver names.

```
string url = "http://silverlight.sms-timing.com/TrackRecord.aspx?siteid=734&language=FRE";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

string driverName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"row0\"]/td[3]")[0].InnerText;
temperatureText3.Text = driverName.ToString();
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] inline in the question (including minimal data necessary to demonstrate problem). Debugging note: In general it is better to select nodes one level at a time while you writing/debugging code - at very least it will let you come up with more specific problem than "my XPath does not do what I want".

Comment: Show the document you are using - maybe it does not contain any element with `id="row0"`?